# Get geojson data from Wikidata

Tags: geojson, wikidata, wikimedia, wikimedia-commons

I request Wikidata entities and get their [geoshape property (P3896)](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Property:P3896).

For example ([try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3Fgeoshape%20%3FgeoshapeLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%3Fitem%20%7B%20wd%3AQ142%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP3896%20%3Fgeoshape.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)):

```sql
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?geoshape ?geoshapeLabel
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?item { wd:Q142 }
  ?item wdt:P3896 ?geoshape.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
```

So I get an url: http://commons.wikimedia.org/data/main/Data:France.map

I tried to fetch data with Javascript:

- `fetch('http://commons.wikimedia.org/data/main/Data:France.map?origin=*')`
- `fetch('https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Data:France.map&action=raw&origin=*')`

But I got error due to CORS policy:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Is there any way to get geojson data from Wikidata from web application?

Comment: to make fetch requests work, add &origin=* to the URL

Comment: I tried `fetch('http://commons.wikimedia.org/data/main/Data:France.map?origin=*')` and `fetch('https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=Data:France.map&action=raw&origin=*')` and I get the same CORS error.

Comment: ok, use `fetch('https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvslots=*&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Data:France.map&origin=*')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [@Pascalo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12780418) we can use

```js
fetch('https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvslots=*&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=Data:France.map&origin=*')
```

The complete JS solution to get geojson data from Wikidata can be the following:

```js
class SPARQLQueryDispatcher {
  constructor(endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
  }
  query(sparqlQuery, simplify = true) {
    const fullUrl = this.endpoint + "?query=" + encodeURIComponent(sparqlQuery);
    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/sparql-results+json"
    };
    return fetch(fullUrl, {
        headers
      })
      .then(body => body.json())
      .then(data => (simplify ? this.simplify(data) : data));
  }
  simplify(data) {
    const bindings = data.results.bindings;
    return bindings.map(binding => {
      Object.keys(binding).forEach(function(key, index) {
        binding[key] = binding[key].value;
      });
      return binding;
    });
  }
}

function buildQuery(ids) {
  const wds = ids.map(id => `wd:${id}`).join(" ");
  return `
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?geoshape ?geoshapeLabel
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?item { ${wds} }
  ?item wdt:P3896 ?geoshape.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
`;
}

function fetchGeojson(rows) {
  const titles = rows
    .filter(r => r.geoshape)
    .map(r => r.geoshape.split("/data/main/").pop())
    .join("|");
  return fetch(`https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvslots=*&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=${titles}&origin=*`)
    .then(r => r.json())
    .then(r => Object.values(r.query.pages))
    .then(r => r.map(r => JSON.parse(r.revisions[0].slots.main["*"]).data));
}

const queryDispatcher = new SPARQLQueryDispatcher("https://query.wikidata.org/sparql");
const query = buildQuery(["Q90"]); // Q90 = Paris

queryDispatcher
  .query(query)
  .then(fetchGeojson)
  .then(console.log);
```